# I have no access to router and portforward and i need to run a webserver

Tags: web-server, nat, tcp, udp, ddns

I got some PCs in some different locations with different ISPs and networks with dynamic ip addresses and I have a dynamic dns server that can records new IPs. but there is a problem.
ISPs blocked all user to buy static ip and do portforward and nat, so when I'm going to the public ip addresses I never reach the modem interfaces or webservers.
I got a situation that I cannot use vpn or a proxy or any need to a third server.

I heard about udp/tcp hole punching and I think it is gonna help me to reach the webservers but how? I don't have any clue. I just need some answers that just show me the way.

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't run web servers on a network of PCs that you can't reach. You're can buy a VPS web server with a static IP address for $5/month.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IPv6, where NATs are not necessary. And the address space is large enough where anyone can get a static prefix.

If you need v4, order static IP addresses. Dynamic DNS only goes so far. It may not update fast enough. Or, the ISP may put you behind multiple layers of NAT and block any hope of reaching you from the outside.

Either way, buy the business class service from the ISP that allows you to run the servers you need. If you can't call them up and get a static prefix and open ports, you have the wrong service.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this will be to use an external traffic forwarding service such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) or Cloudflare [Argo Tunnel](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/) to expose your service on a static external network endpoint.

Alternatively you can run a VPS (server) somewhere on the Internet to forward your traffic, but that will require maintenance itself over time.